# How to achieve the same effect of bouncing against the ceiling without a ceiling?

Tags: flash, off-camera-flash, wireless-flash, umbrella, bounce-flash

Bouncing flash against the ceiling is great, adds a lot to a photo.

My question is how can I achieve this effect without actually bouncing against the ceiling? I have two umbrellas, magmod sphere and magbounce. Is there any way to achieve this using these modifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you want to bounce the flash against the ceiling? Because the ceiling is dark, too high or there is no ceiling?

In such a situation, I think MagBounce or an umbrella is your best option, although it's not an exact replica, as the light is not coming from above. I have considered purchasing such a MagBounce modifier. A flash stand that is as high as possible obviously helps, because that allows the light to come from a high point.

There's always the option of building your own modifiers: [Are any good flash diffusers available apart from DIY paper one?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/105953/are-any-good-flash-diffusers-available-apart-from-diy-paper-one) but I doubt the quality would be better than MagBounce.

Comment: It's too high. I've tried direct flash but not from above. I'll give that a try and keep you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Which aspect are you trying to reproduce? The light from above? You can bounce light off anything, so any large white (or silver, or whatever color you prefer) thing can be held off camera and have the flash pointed at it. You can hold a large white card or similar reflector above the camera and use it to bounce the flash onto the scene. Probably awkward to do alone, but easier with an assistant and a ladder.

You could also get an off-camera flash and simply mount it above the scene pointed downward (probably with something to diffuse it).